# How do I sum up the odd nodes? C program

Tags: c, binary-tree, nodes

How do I return the sum of all odd numbers in the tree?
Must I use recursive to find the sum?

This is my code:

```
int sumOdd(BTreeNode *node)
{
    int sum = 0;
    if(node == NULL)
        return 0;
    else{
        if((node->item % 2) != 0)
            return sum = node->item +
                         sumOdd(node->left) +
                         sumOdd(node->right);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What is `sumOfOddNodes`? How is it related to `sumOdd`? Perhaps you should research how to *emulate pass by reference in c*? And please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be something like this-

```
int sumOdd(BTreeNode *node)
{
    int sum = 0;
    if(node != NULL)
    {
        if((node->item % 2) != 0)
            sum += node->item;
        sum+=sumOdd(node->left);
        sum+=sumOdd(node->right);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

- You shouldn't need to return before you calculate for children nodes.
- You can do it in single method, no need to rewrite another one because the same subproblem is being solved.

You will call it like this

```
int sum = sumOdd(root);
```

You can also modify the `sum`. For that you need to change the method to incorporate `int*` and passing the address.

Comment: but why can't I do ' sum = node->item + sumOdd(node->left) + sumOdd(node->right); '?

Comment: @BEX.: Because youdon't know if `node->item` is odd or even...you can do this `sum=(node->item%2)*node->item+ sumOdd(node->left) + sumOdd(node->right);`